# Javascript library for editing LESS CSS variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

Assuming that I have a website that uses LESS and utilizes variables; I was wondering if a library or anything exists to provide the end-user the ability to change the variable. For example, if the background color of a class is specified in a variable, I would want to be able to edit it in maybe a dropdown menu. I am going to implement something similar, so prior to doing so, was wondering of any existing solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across this problem often lately and after trying many things my solution is to eventually ditch LESS and go with [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/), which has a nice JavaScript API.

In any case, this is what I have working right now to get LESS variables in JavaScript:

```
var getLessVar = function (name, prop) {
  var value = $('<div class="' + name + '"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').css(prop)
  $('.' + name).remove()
  return /^\d+/.test(value) ? +value : value
}
```

It's hacky but works. You create a class in LESS and assign the variable you want to get in JS to a property, let's say `width`, but it can be any other property, depending of the type of data you're sending (numbers, colors...)

```
@myvar: 30px + @foo;
.myvar { width: @myvar }
```

Then in JS you grab the variable with that lil' script like this:

```
var myvar = getLessVar('myvar', 'width')
```

This is not great for performance as it creates an invisible element to retrieve the data but it works.

---

To set a variable from JS is more complicated, but you can always do some AJAX magic together with [`LessPHP`](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) and some basic parser to read your `variables.less`.

But again, if you need more power just go with Stylus.

Comment: Wow thanks for your solution. Even though I may not use it, it really helped me think about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> modifyVars enables modification of LESS variables in run-time. When called with new values, the LESS file is recompiled without reloading. Simple basic usage:

```
less.modifyVars({
    '@buttonFace': '#5B83AD',
    '@buttonText': '#D9EEF2'
});
```